# how do I make a rectangular progress bar that moves around a rectangular screen of a wearable device?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, wearables

I want to make a custom progress bar that is rectangular in shape. meaning Similar to how we can make a round or circular progress bar that can fit on a round screen of a wearable device, I want one that can fit on a rectangular or square watch face.

something like this:

[image]

the only difference it would be around a square watch face like this:

[image]

So it is similar to a circular progressbar like this:
[image]

This is what I achieved so far:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:top="16dp"
        android:bottom="16dp">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="90"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:toDegrees="270">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <size
                            android:width="100dp"
                            android:height="100dp" />
                        <stroke
                            android:width="2dp"
                            android:color="@color/mit_light_grey" />
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but when this file is used in the progressDrawable attribute it simply draws a rectangular shape that rotates. How do I get it to behave as a progressbar?

In short I want the progressbar to display the progress around a rectangular or square screen. I am aware of a library that does that but it is among the libraries that require JCenter which is now deprecated as of March 31st 2021. So I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: you can make that, using custom views and canvas, by handling progress size and with according to screen size.

Comment: is there some sort of example that demonstrates that? I mean can you elaborate or tell me where to look?

Comment: https://github.com/rubiconba/android-sample-batterymeter-custom-view here is the custom battery view by using custom view, paint, canvas etc.

Comment: yes but that doesn't demonstrate how to do it, is there a tutorial of some sorts that explains how to create something like this from scratch?